# android studio 3.1: can custom adapter display null image id?

Tags: java, android-studio

please excuse me for my poor english, my question might look silly, but i wondering how custom array adapter work in the android studio 3.1

first i create a custom adapter to handle my array of object it looks like this:

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

    public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> words){
        // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
        // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
        // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
        // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
        super(context,0,words);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        Word currentWord = getItem(position);

        TextView defaultWord = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);
        defaultWord.setText(currentWord.getDefaultTranslation());

        TextView miwokWord = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view);
        miwokWord.setText(currentWord.getMiwokTranslation());

        ImageView img = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageResource(currentWord.getImageResourceId());
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

my object structure looks like this:

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

public class Word {
    private String mDefaultTranslation;
    private String mMiwokTranslation;
    private int mImageResourceId;

    public Word(String DefaultTranslation, String MiwokTranslation){
        mDefaultTranslation = DefaultTranslation;
        mMiwokTranslation = MiwokTranslation;
    }

    public Word(String DefaultTranslation, String MiwokTranslation, int imageResourceId){
        mDefaultTranslation = DefaultTranslation;
        mMiwokTranslation = MiwokTranslation;
        mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    }

    public String getDefaultTranslation() {
        return mDefaultTranslation;
    }

    public String getMiwokTranslation() {
        return mMiwokTranslation;
    }

    public int getImageResourceId() {
        return mImageResourceId;
    }
}
```

as you can see the word object have 2 constructor the first one takes 2 string values and one int value which is an image resource id, the second one takes only 2 String value.

the code run perfectly with no error which makes me confused because when I use the second object constructor i expected to get an empty list in the activity because the wordAdapter need an image id to work but it works perfectly, any hint guys;